# if downgrading from sharepoint 2010 standard to foundation, would we lose content?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, downgrade

We currently have SharePoint Foundation 2010 installed, and are planning to install a trial of Server Standard 2010.

If the Standard trial runs out, and management decides not to purchase Standard, and we have to revert to Foundation, will we lose content that is stored in site templates that are not available in Foundation? For instance, MySites, Enterprise Wikis, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The content is in the content database and will continue to be there. Basically, you won't have easy access to it.

You could try migrating some of the lists and libraries, including wiki pages for supported page layouts, not Enterprise Wikis. The best way to do that is probably with a 3rd party tool, however. And, if you're not spending money on licensing SharePoint, you probably don't want to pay for a migration tool, either.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. If you have any recommendations for migration tools, I would take a look at them.

Comment: SharePointReviews.com has the most comprehensive lists I know of. Products categorized as Migration or Content Organization may be appropriate http://www.sharepointreviews.com/product-directory/deployment/SharePoint-Products/sharepoint-deployment/sharepoint-migration_c41_m125/ http://www.sharepointreviews.com/product-directory/content-management/SharePoint-Products/sharepoint-management/sharepoint-organization_c35_m119/

Comment: @LCountee Happy to help

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't directly answer your question, but it's probably not such a good idea to install trialware as a production application. You would be best of setting up SP10 on a demo server and using a copy of the production DB...

Comment: We don't have a production DB yet. Some users are evaluating SharePoint functionality. It's hard to get them to do this without letting them add some data that actually matters to them. If it's not possible to retain the data that's fine, just looking for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just performed a downgrade for a client.  Data migrated just fine, but a lot of the internal plumbing is broken, e.g. list/content type gallery.  Of course all pages that use features not available in Foundation do not work, e.g. publishing.